# JQuery loaded form won't submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I load a form via Ajax JQuery like this:

```
$('#quick_feed').load('api/shs/loaders.php?do=ask_question');
```

The form appears, but the problem is when I click the submit button the form does not process a submit. Here is this form

```
<div class="feed_header">
    <div class="feed_profilepic"><img src="profile_pics/<?php echo $session->profile_pic; ?>" width="50" height="50" class="image3" border="0"></div>
    <div class="feed_postedby"><?php echo $session->full_name; ?></div>
    <div class="feed_posted"></div>
</div>

<div class="feed_header" style="padding-top: 3px;">
<form action="?task=submit" method="POST"><input type="text" style="width:  97.7%; color: #000;" class="box" name="question" value="">
</div>

<div class="feed_header" style="padding-top: 2px;">
<textarea rows="10" name="question_more" id="aboutyou" cols="30" style="resize:none; width: 99%"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="feed_header" style="padding-top: 2px;">
</div>

    <div class="feed_header" style="padding-top: 2px;">
    <div class="feed_buttons" id="ask" style="padding-left: 5px;"><p><input type="submit" value="Ask It"></form></p></div>
<a href="#" onClick="AADS(); return false"><div class="feed_buttons" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 0px;"><p><span class="feed_button" style="background-color:#999; margin-top: 3px;">Cancel</span></p></div></a>
</div>
```

The submission of the form is the page that the form was loaded on. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if that could cause any misbehaviour, but you've got your form opening and closing tags quite messed up. You should open and close it on the same level in a visible place.

Comment: my guess goes along with Zoltan. You are rendering the form start inside a div and as such the browser is probably closing it for you as to have it wrapped in a div is invalid.

Comment: i would suggest using the developer tools for your browser and inspect the form. My guess is that you will see that it doesn't encompass your elements like you think.

Comment: Can someone explain how to fix it?

Comment: Remove it from the div it is in

Comment: Thank you I have fixed I just had to place the form submission on the outside of all the divs

Comment: put your opening <form> tag at the top, put your closing </form> at the bottom.  Tags should always be sandwiched.  You don't do `<bread><lettuce></bread></lettuce>

Comment: And, no, you can have a <form> tag inside of divs.  The problem is you do: <div><form></div>...<p></form></p>.  Should be: <form><div></div><p></p></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the form from the div that you wrapped around the `<form>` tag and end the tag at the same level:

```
<form action="?task=submit" method="POST"><input type="text" style="width:  97.7%; color: #000;" class="box" name="question" value="">
   <div class="feed_header" style="padding-top: 2px;">
      <textarea rows="10" name="question_more" id="aboutyou" cols="30" style="resize:none; width: 99%"></textarea>
   </div>

   <div class="feed_header" style="padding-top: 2px;">
   </div>

    <div class="feed_header" style="padding-top: 2px;">
       <div class="feed_buttons" id="ask" style="padding-left: 5px;">
          <p><input type="submit" value="Ask It"></p>
       </div>
       <a href="#" onClick="AADS(); return false">
          <span class="feed_buttons" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-top: 0px;">
              <span class="feed_button" style="background-color:#999; margin-top: 3px;">Cancel</span>
          </span> 
       </a>
    </div>
</form>
```